# BufferedReader gives Connection reset?

Tags: java, networking, tcp

I'm trying to send some data from a client to a server using Java, here is my PlayerThread which is ran on the server when a new client connects

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        //Create a link to send data to the server
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(
                socket.getInputStream()));
        while(true)
        {
            out.println(pongData);
            String temp = in.readLine();
            if(temp == "up")
            {
                System.out.println("Up you say");
            }
        }
//There is a little more but no point to give it all
```

The line String temp = in.readLine();
gives me this error when the client disconnects

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(Unknown Source)
at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
at Pong.PongPlayerThread.run(PongPlayerThread.java:36)
```

Here is the client code

```
try
    {
        socket = new Socket(host, port);
        serverOut = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        serverInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
    }
    catch (UnknownHostException e)
    {
        System.err.println("Couold not connect to host:" + host);
        System.exit(1);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        System.err.println("Could not get Input/Output from server");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    System.out.println("Connected to Server");

    while ((pos = serverInput.readLine()) != null) 
    {
        String[] posValues = pos.split(":");
        model.getBall().setX(Double.parseDouble(posValues[0]));
        model.getBall().setY(Double.parseDouble(posValues[1]));

        if(PongController.moveUp == true)
        {
            serverOut.println("up");
            PongController.moveUp = false;
        }

        //If the client presses up or down arrow, a message will be sent to the server
        //the server will then update the movement and the clients will be able to see it

    }
```

This code works, but it doesn't seem to actually send the message up at all :(, If anyone could help me that would be awesome

Canvas

I have just editted some code and I have found out that in the PlayerThread the lines

```
if(temp.equals("up"))
            {
                System.out.println("Up you say");
            }
```

is the problem, my stream on the client side is set to nothing at the start, could that be the problem? sending null?

this is the updated version

```
    while ((pos = serverInput.readLine()) != null) 
    {
        String[] posValues = pos.split(":");
        model.getBall().setX(Double.parseDouble(posValues[0]));
        model.getBall().setY(Double.parseDouble(posValues[1]));
        serverOut.println("nothing");

        if(PongController.moveUp == true)
        {
            System.out.println("Up");
            serverOut.println("up");
            PongController.moveUp = false;
        }
        else
        {
            serverOut.println("nothing");
        }

    }
```

but I still get the same error

Checking to see if the in.readLine is equal to anything i get this 
here is the code

```
try
    {
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
         BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(
                    socket.getInputStream()));

         System.out.println("Checking readLine value");

         if(in.readLine() == null)
         {
             System.out.println("A ok");
         }
         else
         {
             System.out.println(":" + in.readLine());
         }

        while(true)
        {
             String temp = in.readLine();
             if(temp == "up")
             {
                    System.out.println("Up you say");
             }
            out.println(pongData);
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

here is the outcome

```
Pong
400.0:301.0:60.0:300.0:740.0:300.0
Server started
Server was setup and will try to create a socket
Data sent
Checking readLine value
Connection reset, and then followed by lots of red lines
```

What else can i do?

I just tried to check on my BufferedReader like so

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(
                    socket.getInputStream()));

        System.out.println(in.toString());
        System.out.println(in.readLine());
```

I get java.io.BufferedReader@6262937c for the in.toString
but for the readLine i get the connection reset again...

Quick update,

In my client code, if i have this

```
 while ((pos = serverInput.readLine()) != null) 
    {
        String[] posValues = pos.split(":");
        model.getBall().setX(Double.parseDouble(posValues[0]));
        model.getBall().setY(Double.parseDouble(posValues[1]));
        serverOut.println("nothing"); //<---
```

the client will connect, get the position of the pong ball, but then it will stop recieveing data from the server and just move the ball on its own accord (update method hasnt been disabled yet). the serverOut  is

```
serverOut = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
```

Comment: Aside from anything else, you're comparing strings incorrectly... see http://tinyurl.com/so-java-string-equality

Comment: What you're seeing for the connection reset is documented behavior, and this is why most communications protocols today include the length of the message they're sending, such as HTTP's `Content-Length` header value.

Comment: Ok Jon I have changed it, but still get the same error

Comment: Brian, I followed a tutorial and it worked fine on the tutorial, I just can't seem to get it to work for mine, there most be other reasons why it would come up with this.

Comment: Are you sure that condition `PongController.moveUp == true` is returning `true` ?

Comment: It only does if the user is pressing a key, maybe I should add a else statement?

Comment: @Canvas  if user does not press a key then...`PongController.moveUp` becomes `false`..and you condition becomes false..and consequently you are not sending anything to server in `else`(which you have not mentioned in your code) `block`. So server hangs on String `temp = in.readLine();` and client hangs on `pos = serverInput.readLine()`. I guess that your program is hanged up when user is'nt pressing any key i.e. when `PongController.moveUp` is `false`

Comment: so i need to give it atleast something to send, even though the server will do nothing with it yea?

Comment: Yeah absolutely right..And handle that something at server side also to understand the motivation of client...

Comment: Ok changed it but still it doesn't work at all :(

Comment: You also need to check for `readLine()` returning null before you do anything else with the value. If you get null, the peer has closed the connection and you must do likewise, and exit the read loop of course.

Comment: I will try that soon and update you on the status :)

Comment: Well if i remove the whole piece of code that does the BufferedReader, my server allows two clients to connect to it and the server will send data to both threads (which hold the clients), which then the threads send the data to the clients, and the pong ball location is updated, this all works fine.

Comment: Ok, so how would you go around sending data from the client to the server?

Comment: Also: Wouldn't `if (in.readLine() == null)` empty the read buffer?

Comment: Well I'm not sure, but if I check it, it throws the error at me, the line--- if(in.readLine() == null)--- throws the error

Comment: You get this `Connection reset` on the client side?

Comment: Forget my comment on block/non-blocking.

Comment: Nope that is the server, the client has no problem connection and just closing, but the server gets the error once the client closing the program, also you say not to use BufferedReader, how can i read input if I dont have a inputStream? what can i write to? If i put this line in the client just after the while statement --- serverOut.println("nothing"); --- the client will get one packet from the server, then not update again, when i close the client no errors, and the server gets no errors (i did remove trying to read from the client as the server).

Comment: Also just for clarity, the server class does not have a input stream or output stream, the thread class deals with that

Comment: Ok in my client I had this ---String text = "nothing";
      serverOut.println(text);
      String[] posValues = pos.split(":");
      model.getBall().setX(Double.parseDouble(posValues[0]));
      model.getBall().setY(Double.parseDouble(posValues[1]));---
I added your code and i got this

if ((line = in.readLine()) == null) is Connection reset :(

Comment: Would you like me to delete most of the information in my post, and just put what I have now into, so it can be a bit more clear.

Comment: No, better leave this as is. Boil down your code to a reasonable small example which shows the behaviour in question but is complete, so other could try it out. And then post this as another question. It is then up to you to delete this question.

Comment: Ok i will post a new question very soon, cheers for all the help, hopefully someone can get it working :)

Comment: Use explicit encoding on both sides on every reader and writer. If you run on different systems read/ write line may create problems.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok so I've noticed you have been asking a lot of questions about networking recently and I figured maybe you need some help with the basics. This is an extremely simple server:

```
package com;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class SimpleServer implements Runnable
{    
    public SimpleServer()
    {
        started = false;
        serverSocket = null;
    }

    public void start()
    {
        if(!started)
        {
            started = true;

            try
            {
                serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);
                running = true;

                serverThread = new Thread(this);
                serverThread.start();

                System.out.println("Server started!\n");
            }catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    }

    public void stop()
    {
        running = false;
        started = false;

        if(serverThread != null)
            serverThread.interrupt();
        serverThread = null;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            while(running)
            {
                try
                {
                    Socket client = serverSocket.accept();
                    System.out.println("Client Accepted!");

                    ClientHandler handler = new ClientHandler(client);

                    handler.sendMessage("Hello, SimpleClient!");
                    System.out.println("Sendeing client a message...");
                }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
            }
        }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
    }

    private boolean started;
    private boolean running;
    private ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private Thread serverThread;

    private static final int PORT = 8081;

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        SimpleServer server = new SimpleServer();
        server.start();
    }

    public class ClientHandler implements Runnable
    {
        public ClientHandler(Socket socket)
        {
            this.socket = socket;

            try
            {
                writer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                running = true;

                runningThread = new Thread(this);
                runningThread.start();
            }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace(); disconnect();}
        }

        public void disconnect()
        {
            running = false;
            if(runningThread != null)
                runningThread.interrupt();
            runningThread = null;

            try
            {
                reader.close();
            }catch(Exception e){}
            reader = null;

            try
            {
                writer.close();
            }catch(Exception e){}
            writer = null;
            try
            {
                socket.close();
            }catch(Exception e){}
            socket = null;
        }

        public void sendMessage(String message)
        {
            if(running)
            {
                writer.println(message);
                writer.flush();
            }
        }

        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                String message = "";
                while((message = reader.readLine()) != null && running)
                {
                    System.out.println("Message Recieved: " + message);
                }
            }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace(); disconnect();}
        }

        private Socket socket;
        private PrintWriter writer;
        private BufferedReader reader;

        private Thread runningThread;
        private boolean running;
    }
}
```

and now here is the client:

```
package com;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;

public class SimpleClient implements Runnable
{
    public SimpleClient()
    {
        try
        {
            socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", PORT);
            writer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            running = true;

            runningThread = new Thread(this);
            runningThread.start();
        }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace(); disconnect();}
    }

    public void disconnect()
    {
        running = false;
        if(runningThread != null)
            runningThread.interrupt();
        runningThread = null;

        try
        {
            reader.close();
        }catch(Exception e){}
        reader = null;

        try
        {
            writer.close();
        }catch(Exception e){}
        writer = null;
        try
        {
            socket.close();
        }catch(Exception e){}
        socket = null;
    }

    public void sendMessage(String message)
    {
        if(running)
        {
            writer.println(message);
            writer.flush();
        }
    }

    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            String message = "";
            while((message = reader.readLine()) != null && running)
            {
                System.out.println("Message Recieved: " + message);

                System.out.println("Sending a response!");
                sendMessage("Hello, SimpleServer!");
            }
        }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace(); disconnect();}
    }

    private Socket socket;
    private PrintWriter writer;
    private BufferedReader reader;

    private Thread runningThread;
    private boolean running;

    private static final int PORT = 8081;

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        new SimpleClient();
    }
}
```

In order to make a successful server in Java you need to implement a lot of Object Orientation. The server would be too complex if it had to deal with not only listening for clients but also sending and receiving messages to and from those clients. This is why I usually use a `ClientHandler` class. This class handles all of the communication and is very easy to implement. The client and the server should never be in the same file because they are meant to be run separately.

This also might interest you if you aren't sure exactly how server and clients should work:

- [Client - Server Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client%E2%80%93server_model)

I hope this helped!

John

Comment: I will take a look very soon, and will defiently give it ago, I am new to networking and it seems so complex to just coding a program :D, but cheers for the post, will have a go soon

Comment: Ok, if you have any more questions let me know, or if you need more example code let me know, cheers!

Comment: John, is it possible at all you can have a look at my other question? I got some help for it, but I'm a little stuck on another error now, and I'm not sure if the client needs its own thread to recieve data and send it. the link is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14914027/java-client-to-server-unknown-source

Comment: Something that i don't understand here - what is the big difference of this code to his approach, what did he do wrong? (apart from organization of code)

Comment: @kutschkem when I looked at his code I didn't see anything immediately wrong with it. I saw that it had poor structure. He was using a blocking server without running it on a separate thread which is a structure problem. He also was not running each client connection on it's own thread which was also poor structure. The code was there, the structure was not. Networking is very complex and requires good structure to function properly.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to flush the output.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#flush()

Comment: Just changed my code to this

      if(PongController.moveUp == true)
      {
       serverOut.println("up");
       serverOut.flush();
       System.out.println("is did send");
       PongController.moveUp = false;
      }

but still nothing :(

Comment: Have you considered using WireShark to watch the TCP stream?

Comment: Nope never used it, is it easy to use?

Comment: Not super easy, but it's worth a shot: http://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChAdvFollowTCPSection.html

Comment: how can i tell it just to listen for 127.0.0.1 packets?

Comment: You can right-click fields in the lower pane to build filters, that will at least give you an idea for the syntax for the filter field in the tool bar.

Comment: @Charlie Wireshark won't even see packets to/from 127.0.0.1. They don't go on the wire.

Comment: You may need to configure a loopback adapter. A quick google for 'wireshark localhost windows' might shed some light.