# Java Client to Server Unknown Source

Tags: java, sockets, networking, tcp

I have a simple pong game that needs to work over a network, the server will create a game with the positions of the ball and 2 bats, when a client connects to the server, the server will create a new class known PongPlayerThread which will deal with the input and output streams of the client to server,

My server works 100% fine without any data from the client to the server, the server can send information to the client without any problems, but I have a strange problem, But first here is my code, so you can see what I have.

PongServer

```
try
{
    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
    listen = true;
    System.out.println("Server was setup and will try to create a socket");
}
catch(IOException e)
{
    System.err.println("Could not listen on port:" + port);
    System.exit(1);
}

while(listen)
{
    players[idPlayer] = new PongPlayerThread(serverSocket.accept(), idPlayer, rtnInfo());
    players[idPlayer].start();
    System.out.println("Client Connected with ID:" + idPlayer);
    players[0].passData(rtnInfo());
    idPlayer++;     
    if(idPlayer > 1)
    {
        listen = false;
        playing = true;
    }
}

while(playing)
{
    players[0].passData(rtnInfo());
    players[0].sleep(25);
    players[1].passData(rtnInfo());
    players[1].sleep(25);
}

....//more, but not important
```

Here is my PongClient

```
try
{
    socket = new Socket(host, port);
    serverOut = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
    serverInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
}
catch (UnknownHostException e)
{
    System.err.println("Couold not connect to host:" + host);
    System.exit(1);
}
catch (IOException e)
{
    System.err.println("Could not get Input/Output from server");
    System.exit(1);
}

...

while ((pos = serverInput.readLine()) != null) 
{
    String text = "nothing";
    serverOut.println(text);
    String[] posValues = pos.split(":");
        model.getBall().setX(Double.parseDouble(posValues[0]));
        model.getBall().setY(Double.parseDouble(posValues[1]));


    /*if(PongController.moveUp == true)
    {
        System.out.println("Up");
        serverOut.println("up");
        PongController.moveUp = false;
    }
    else
    {
        serverOut.println("nothing");
    }*/

}
```

Here is my PongPlayerThread

```
try
{
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(
        socket.getInputStream()));

    String text = "hhh";

    System.out.println(in.toString());
    //System.out.println(text = in.readLine());
    System.out.println("Checking readLine value");

    String line; 
    if ((line = in.readLine()) == null) 
    { 
        System.out.println("A ok"); 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        System.out.println(":" + line); 
    }

    while(send)
    {
        //String temp = in.readLine();
        //if(temp.equals("up"))
        //{
        //        System.out.println("Up you say");
        //}
        out.println(pongData);
    }

    out.close();
    in.close();
    socket.close();
}

catch (IOException e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Now when I run my server it is fine, I then connect a client, when a client connects the pong ball should sit still while it waits for another player, but the ball will just update itself without getting data from the server, once I close the clients program, my server will come up with this error

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(Unknown Source)
at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
at Pong.PongPlayerThread.run(PongPlayerThread.java:42)
```

The line 42 in PongPlayerThread is this

```
if ((line = in.readLine()) == null)
```

I have been trying to fix this for days, but I have still not found the solution, I feel like the inputStream cannot connect to the outputStream of the client, I have tried to use wireShark but this is a LAN program, so it won't work and nothing will show up in wireShark. If anyone could shine some light onto this, It would be much appreciated.

Canvas

iTech update
Ok I have used your code here is what is in my PongPlayerThread now

```
public void run()
{
    try
    {
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(
                    socket.getInputStream()));

        String text = "hhh";

        System.out.println(in.toString());
        //System.out.println(text = in.readLine());
         System.out.println("Checking readLine value");

         String line = null; 
         if ((line = in.readLine()) != null) // why you check if it is null !?
         { 
             System.out.println("Client sent: "+line); 
         } 

        while(send)
        {
            out.println(pongData);
        }

         out.close();
         in.close();
         socket.close();
    }
```

this will say in console "Client sent: Hello", but my client will not stop and keep taking in data from the server,

If i put the if statement you gave me into the while statement which has out.println(pongData) it works but I get a error once a client connects and disconnects, or i get a error if two clients connect and then they both leave i get this error again :(

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(Unknown Source)
at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
at Pong.PongPlayerThread.run(PongPlayerThread.java:45)
```

and line 45 is

```
if ((line = in.readLine()) != null) // why you check if it is null !?
```

Sorted the code out, but now in my pongClient code

```
 while ((pos = serverInput.readLine()) != null) 
    {
        String text = "nothing";
        serverOut.println(text);
        String[] posValues = pos.split(":");
        model.getBall().setX(Double.parseDouble(posValues[0]));
        model.getBall().setY(Double.parseDouble(posValues[1]));


        if(PongController.moveUp == true)
        {
            System.out.println("Up");
            serverOut.println("up");
            PongController.moveUp = false;
        }
        else
        {
            serverOut.println("nothing");
        }

    }
```

Once it hits this, it wont do anything, and will cause the whole error again.

I found the error, where i had put

```
 if ((line = in.readLine()) != null)
             {
```

if you put line = in.readLine() again, it will cause an error. strange, but it is fixed now, and data can be sent from the client to server, and server to client :)

Comment: Where do you create your thread?? And why do you create a `BufferedReader` and a `PrintWriter` for the socket twice? (1 for the client and another one for the thread??)

Comment: I'm quite new to networking and I just followed the tutorial of the KnockKnockServer at the oracle java website, i create a printWriter and bufferedReader for the client and thread yep, also the thread is started by the server, in the while(listen) statement, at the top of the file for the PongServer i have a variable declared like so private static PongPlayerThread players[] = new PongPlayerThread[2];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once a client connects to your server the `if ((line = in.readLine()) == null)` will block the thread until a message is received from the client.

You need to send something from the client after the connection is established

In `PongPlayerThread` you can modify the following and remove the `else` block

```
String line = null; 
if ((line = in.readLine()) != null) // why you check if it is null !?
{ 
    System.out.println("Client sent: "+line); 
}
```

In `PongClient` after establishing the `socket` connection, you can send some message, e.g. `serverOut.println("Hello");`

Comment: Please look at my post to see what I have and what happens

Comment: What is the problem now? the error you are getting when you disconnect is normal, since you are waiting for input `readLine` and then the stream is closed

Comment: Ah ok, then that is fine, cheers for the help iTech I can actually start to try and move on :D

Comment: Ok nope still got a small error, In my while state for the pongClient i want to send a string over to tell the server to move my bat up, the code is updated in my post

Comment: I think you need to cleanup your entire question, make concise and contain only the necessary code for the problem you have at the moment. In general, if you want to maintain a two-way communication between the server and the client. You need a **dedicated** reading thread in both sides

Comment: What, so the client needs a thread that will send the data to the server?

Comment: If you have a dedicated reading thread, so you can execute write operation in the main thread. It all depend on your program logic.

Comment: Your statement "the error you are getting when you disconnect is normal, since you are waiting for input readLine and then the stream is closed" doesn't begin to make sense. If the client disconnected, `readLine()` would return null. If he had closed the socket himself, it would throw `SocketException: socket closed`. In neither case would it block.

Answer (score 0):

'Connection reset' has several causes, but the most common one is that you have written to a connection that had already been closed by the other end. In other words, an application protocol error.